# Powerquery/Powerpivot/Excel tables

Tags: excel, powerpivot, powerquery

I'm importing some Access data ranges to powerquery and afterwards I'm doing some calculated columns in PowerPivot. 
Finally I'm loading the entire range into Excel.

This works quite will, right up till I need to do some changes in powerquery, which causes the columns in excel to be shuffled around seemingly at random and messes up all my formula references?

If I break the connections to PowerPivot and remove the excel ranges and reload everything (including recalculating all the columns in powerpivot) then the excel columns are in the correct order again.

Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: if you are loading a query to a table, check that "Preserve column sort/filter/layout" is checked in "External data properties"

Comment: In addition to @ygaft 's suggestion, for such cases I may suggest to use Table header references in your formulas instead of standard A1 type references. This way, your formulas do not get scrambled when the column locations change. Even though your above problem is resolved, you may want to add or remove a column at some phase, which standard cell references will again be a problem.

Comment: @ygaft thanks that seems to work!

Comment: @HakanERDOGAN I actually already to use header references, but they get scrampled up anyway.

Comment: @ygaft I had a second look at it all and it seems that it doesn't work as I thought it did.
The External data properties seem to be tied to the specific data range, and not the data model. That means if I remove the range and reload the data model to a new range, the columns will be again. I somehow need to apply the "Preserve column sort/filter/layout" to the data model?

Comment: @Martin Please explain your flow: Load data from MS Access via PowerQuery --> Manipulation via PowerPivot --> Extracting PowerPivot to a table in Excel? what are the manipulations on the PowerQuery stage? if you are adding columns, they will be added at the end of your table in PowerPivot which will not preserve the structure, same goes if you'll rearrange columns in the query. Overall I would suggest using Index+Match for that kind of problem. If you could paste some sample what you are trying to achieve it would be easier...

Comment: @Ygaft the flow you mention is correct. Often after I've done the steps you mention I find out that I need some other column which I then go back to PowerQuery to add (and put in what ever order makes sense), I then go to PowerPivot and update what ever needs updating there and maybe rearrange some columns there as well so it matches. But when I then update the columns in the excel table everything is scrambled.
I have tried to show the flow here: [https://imgur.com/a/vkBv7mT](https://imgur.com/a/vkBv7mT)
I have tried to update the data in PowerPivot Excel and PowerQuery individually as well

Comment: @Martin I see. Basically I am not a huge fan of extracting PP table to excel table. You should re-visit the overall flow and your final target. You can PM me. Might give you some advice :) (jacky.gaft@gmail.com) . Cheers